# Why my python code doesn't print in a separate thread? (IronPython)

Tags: python, .net, ironpython

I'm not sure, what I did wrong:
So, I started a thread with the ThreadStart()-delegate from the .net-libary.
It's delegating to another method.
In the method I have a for-loop.
But when I'm looking in the console, I can't find any text.

```
def Loop():
   for i in range(0,10):
     print(i)

Updating_Thread = Thread(ThreadStart(Loop))
Updating_Thread.Start()
```

Comment: You main thread terminates right after you start the new thread. You should `.join()` your thread to keep the main thread running.

Comment: No, my main-thread is the GUI-Thread. I forgot to add this information...
The GUI-Thread will end at least.